# How to avoid the error for a valid Python code on Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
from typing import Any, NamedTuple, Mapping, Optional
class Myclass(NamedTuple):
    my_tenant_id: str
    my_firstname_name: str
    my_iphone_version: int
    my_otherdetails: Optional[Mapping]
```

Python 3.6.6 says

> Unresolved reference

at every line wherever `:` appears

Comment: Are you sure that you are using python 3.6.6? I had to set python3.6 in environment settings for it to work

Comment: please post a proper MCVE - there's nothing named "NamedTuple" in the stdlib.

Comment: I am using Python 3.6.6 as well as tried on 3.6.7 on Pycharm.It says Unresolved Reference despite me importing from typing import Any, NamedTuple, Mapping, Optional

Comment: from typing import Any, NamedTuple, Mapping, Optional
class Myclass(NamedTuple):
    my_tenant_id: str
    my_firstname_name: str
    my_iphone_version: int
    my_otherdetails: Optional[Mapping]

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem on 3.6.7.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use type annotation, you'll have to assign the value as well.

```
my_tenant_id: str = ""
my_first_name: str = ""
```

python cannot predefine a variable without assigning values.

**Update**: It seems python's type annotation allows declaration of class variables without values. 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple

Comment: This is a _class_ definition, not a variable definition. The posted code is valid.

Comment: Oh that is new for me. It seems you are correct. I read previously that pythons' type annotation is just for syntactic sugar. It doesn't add any new feature. But apparently in this case it does. Without `: str` python complains that the variable is undefined, but with `: str` it doesn't.